# Are both NotificationCompat and NotificationCompat.Style obsolete when I use Android Studio 4.0?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I'm learning Notifications.

There is a sample project [user-interface-samples](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/Notifications), I find many files in the project exists Code A.

But the [artical](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat) tell me "*NotificationCompat is obsolete*", please see Image A

1:  Code A use latest androidx namesapce, why is it obsolete?

2:  Is there a sample project about Notifications based AndroidX which is part of Jetpack.

**Code A**

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
```

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the documentation for `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`, part of the pre-AndroidX Support Libraries. That class is deprecated, but you aren't using that version, so the documentation there is irrelevant.

The AndroidX equivalent, [`androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat) is not deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a fork of user-interface-samples about Notifications based Kotlin?

Comment: Nope, that is the latest sample. Just looks like a few links that haven't been updated. Sounds like a good pull request / issue in that repository though :-)